# Removing label from legend when using scale_alpha_manual in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to hide a bar in my graph and still keep its place, so I am using `scale_alpha_manual` to hide that bar. How can I remove the hidden label from the legend as well?

```
df <- structure(list(variable = c("Oil", "Oil", "Gas", "Gas"), case = c("ces", 
"disrupted", "ces", "disrupted"), delta = c(7.52, -0.27, 1.13, 
0.02)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

ggplot(data = df
       ,aes(x=variable, y = delta  , fill=case,
            alpha = factor(case)
       ) ) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c("ces"= 1, "disrupted"=0.001), guide='none') +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(ncol=1,title=""))
```

In this case I want to remove the "disrupted" label from the legend.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `+ scale_fill_discrete(breaks = 'ces')` to your plot:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(variable, delta, fill = case, alpha = case)) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = 1:0, guide = 'none') +
  scale_fill_discrete(NULL, breaks = 'ces') +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]